# Create a fully static C++ binary in Bazel

Tags: c++, gcc, bazel

Is it possible to create a fully static binary in Bazel or is there a bug in GCC or Bazel preventing me?

This is the error that I get

```
/bin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginT.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against '__TMC_END__' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

Which if I understand correctly is a version libstdc++ that is not statically linked. Was wondering if there was a version of libstdc++ that is statically linked that I could make Bazel use.

Tried looking at this issue on Bazel's repo but the workarounds mentioned do not work for me

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8672

#### Info Dump

- Bazel version:`3.3.1`
- GCC version: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 in a Docker container

My build file

```
cc_binary(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["main.cpp"],
  linkshared=True,
  copts = ["-shared", "-fpic", "-fPIC"],
  features = ["fully_static_link"],
)
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  return 1;
}
```

#### Other versions of the build file with similar results

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    linkshared=True,
    linkstatic=1,
    linkopts = ["-static"]
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    linkshared=True,
    linkstatic=1,
    linkopts = ["-static"],
    features = ["fully_static_link"],
    copts=["-fpic"],
)
```

#### TL;DR

Bazel will not compile a fully static binary in Ubuntu 20.04, GCC 9.3.0. I'm seeking to understand if the issue posted is related or if I don't understand something about static linking?

Comment: I don't know bazel, but it's odd you're using `linkshared` and `-shared` options for something you want to statically link.

Comment: Mostly because of these docs. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary  If you specify both linkopts=['-static'] and linkshared=True, you get a single completely self-contained unit. If you specify both linkstatic=1 and linkshared=True, you get a single, mostly self-contained unit

Comment: `linkshared` says that it creates a shared library.  This also explains why you're using `-shared` in your flags since it does the same thing.  You're not specifying `linkstatic` in your example though, and you don't have `static` in your `linkopts`.

Comment: Yep sorry for the confusion. I've worked through several iterations of this BUILD file. The `fully_static_link` parameter adds the linkstatic and the `-static` to the linkopts which is why I didn't specify it above. I've edited the question to show other versions of the build file (including explicit `linkstatic` and `-shared`)

Comment: also seeing this